# undefined method `require_relative' for main:Object (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

When trying to update OpenSSL - I broke (seemingly) everything surrounding Ruby and Rails on my laptop. Even after uninstalling ruby and rails through `gem uninstall` and `rvm remove`I am still running into this error:

```
Drews-MacBook-Pro:bookstore drewwyatt$ rails server
bin/rails:3: undefined method `require_relative' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

Everything has been working fine for months until I went mucking around - the worse part is that I'm not even sure what I did to mess things up.

**extra info**

```
Drews-MacBook-Pro:bookstore drewwyatt$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-darwin12.3.0]
Drews-MacBook-Pro:bookstore drewwyatt$ which ruby
/Users/drewwyatt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby
Drews-MacBook-Pro:bookstore drewwyatt$ rails -v
bin/rails:3: undefined method `require_relative' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
Drews-MacBook-Pro:bookstore drewwyatt$ which rails
/Users/drewwyatt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/rails
Drews-MacBook-Pro:bookstore drewwyatt$
```

**update - installing without sudo**

```
Drews-MacBook-Pro:~ drewwyatt$ gem install rails
Fetching: railties-4.0.0.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied - /Users/drewwyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_executable_hooks
Drews-MacBook-Pro:~ drewwyatt$
```

Comment: This is really strange. Maybe you should go back system installed openssl.

Comment: require_relative being undefined is usually a sign that you're on a lower ruby than 1.9. since that doesn't seem to be the problem, what rails version are you running?

Comment: @MikeH-R Should be rails 4. When I reinstalled I just ran `sudo gem install rails`

Comment: The stack trace tells it's running ruby 2.0.0

Comment: @IsmaelAbreu Yes, that is correct. Ruby 2, Rails 4

Comment: The `sudo` may well have lost enough of your environment to do something funny for the install (such as install it using your system Ruby). Try a `sudo gem uninstall rails`, then  a `gem install rails`, *without* the `sudo`.

Comment: @NeilSlater Just added an update - that's wht I had to use sudo last time. any ideas?

Comment: It happened when I tried to run 'rails server' after installing a new version of jruby (1.7.4 to 1.7.5) in a different console. (I opened two consoles.) But it worked with reopening a console.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**I fixed the problem by completely removing Rails, Ruby, and RVM altogether - then starting from scratch.**

I don't remember all of the commands exactly, but it was something like:

```
sudo gem uninstall rails
sudo rvm remove 2.0
rvm implode
sudo chown -R drewwyatt: ~/.rvm/
rm -rf ~/.rvm
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails
rvm use 2.0
gem install rails
```

Comment: This seems a bit heavy-handed as a starting place. I'd encourage people to start with the solution below and work to this answer if a simple `gem install rails` doesn't work, updating everything to 4.0.0 (especially true for Ruby/Rails noobs)

Answer (score 10):

This came up for me after installing rails with Rails Composer. Seems like a problem with RVM selecting the ruby version, the trick was to simply navigate out and back into the folder.

`$ cd ..`
`$ cd myapp`

Answer (score 6):

I was able to resolve this problem by simply running `gem install rails`.

This problem occurred when I cloned a pre-existing Rails 4 app. I am using ruby-2.0.0-p317, and an RVM gemset specific to this app. I ran the initial `bundle install`, but then could not run `rails console` without getting the error.

After running `gem install rails`, which used the cached copy in my app's gemset, the problem was resolved. Don't ask my why!

Comment: Same deal with my answer. I feel like a lot of my "command line problems" end up being fixed in ways that make me think "not sure why that works, but thank god it did."

Comment: This also appeared to resolve it for me as well with ruby `2.0.0-p0` and rails `4.0.0`

Comment: This did it for me. This should solve any weirdness if you're in the phase where you're juggling Ruby 1.9.x or Rails 3.x and upgrade to Ruby 2 and Rails 4

Answer (score 4):

Try running `bundle exec rails server` instead of just `rails server`.

I was seeing this error because I had a conflicting version of the `rails` gem installed globally.

Prefixing commands with `bundle exec` ensures that you're using gems specified by your project's `Gemfile.lock`.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @ncherro, I got this using ruby filename.rb.  Running

```
bundle exec ruby filename.rb
```

works.