# Trouble with Rails installation, how do I delete Ruby/Rails and start from scratch?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

After spending hours trying to figure out what went wrong with my Rails installation, I've decided it will be easiest to simply start over and begin everything anew.

I can't simply uninstall rails - I get tons of errors. How can I just delete everything and get my Mac back to a fresh start?

Comment: How did you try to remove Rails? What errors did you get? How did you install Rails? These questions may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430059/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-rails-ruby-and-rubygems http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16164697/uninstall-rails-completely

Comment: If you are using rvm, you can do rvm implode.  To uninstall the rails gem uninstall rails

Comment: i can't even see what gems i have this is my message - gem list
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in `parse': (<unknown>): could not find expected ':' while scanning a simple key at line 3 column 1 (Psych::SyntaxError)
 from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in `parse_stream'
 from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:46:in `run'
 from /usr/bin/gem:21:in `<main>'

Comment: the error went much longer but i cut it off b/c there were too many characters.

Comment: [I had a similar issue. Maybe my solution will help?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18934716/undefined-method-require-relative-for-mainobject-nomethoderror/19942026?noredirect=1#19942026

Answer (score 0):

Moving forward, use RVM, then if something goes wrong, instead of spending hours, you just destroy it in RVM and start from scratch in minutes.