# Running rails-0.9.5 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gemfile

I was getting an error with my application, so I looked on stack and found an answer [undefined method `require_relative' for main:Object (NoMethodError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18934716/undefined-method-require-relative-for-mainobject-nomethoderror) it said that I should run `gem install rails` which I did, after I ran that, when I tried to run `rails generate controller StaticPages home help --no-test-framework`
 I got an error:

```
(in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rails-0.9.5)
rake aborted!
ERROR: 'rake/rdoctask' is obsolete and no longer supported. Use 'rdoc/task' (available in RDoc 2.4.2+) instead.
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rails-0.9.5/Rakefile:3:in `<top (required)>'
```

It says that I am running rails .95 and even when I ran `gem update rails` nothing happend

Here is my gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'

gem 'rails', '4.0.2'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

Comment: try to run `bundle exec rails generate ...`

Comment: @gotva Do you happen to know why I need to run bundle exec because I have never needed to run that before

Comment: Actually you should do it for `rails`, `rake`, `rspec` etc. because Bundle knows what exactly versions of gems are used in the APP (Bundler takes versions from `Gemfile.lock`) - it means command will be started from correct source. PS if you haven't read about bundle - read [about bundler](http://bundler.io/) PPS did it help you?

Comment: @gotva Would the command be  `bundle install .. ` to install the new versions of the rake, rspec and rails

Comment: it depends on your local environment. If you have `Gemfile.lock` and you have already run `bundle install` then NO `bundle` finds already installed gems and will use them.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting your `Gemfile.lock` (or perhaps moving it). This worked for me.